# How to use c_void_p as a handle

Tags: python, ctypes, handle

I have a .dll I'm trying to access using ctypes. The header for the .dll looks like this:

```
typedef void* CMS_HANDLE;
CMS_HANDLE  WINAPI cmsOpen( int nDeviceID , int nComType);
BOOL        WINAPI cmsClose(CMS_HANDLE hCms);
```

My python code looks like this:

```
from ctypes import WinDLL, c_void_p, c_double, byref
dll = WinDLL("CMS_APIX64.dll")
handle = c_void_p(dll.cmsOpen(15, 3))
print(handle)
dll.cmsClose(handle)
```

It does the dll.cmsOpen correctly and returns a value. However, it doesn't like the value I pass into dll.cmsClose():

```
c_void_p(18446744072525716064)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mjwilson\dev\Cms100-tool\cms100-tool.py", line 40, in <module>
    dll.cmsClose(handle)
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFFB9701A60
```

I'm sure I'm just doing something dumb with the handle. Any ideas?
(I have C-code that works with this .dll)

Comment: Was it compiled as win32 with a 32 bit pointer size? But you're on a 64bit python? Just random guessing since that's what the integer looks like.

Comment: Dll is supposed to be 64 bit (64 in the dll name, as shown, and python is 64 bit. I have access to the .lib file, but not the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on 64-bit Python, handles are 64-bit, but ctypes assumes return types are `c_int` (32-bit) if not specifically defined, so the `cmsOpen` return value is already truncated when you put it into a `c_void_p`.

What is *always* good practice, is to fully define both `.argtypes` and `.restype` for each function you use.  This will convert parameters correctly, and provide error checking if passed incorrect or wrong number of arguments:

```
from ctypes import *

dll = WinDLL("CMS_APIX64.dll")
dll.cmsOpen.argtypes = c_int,c_int
dll.cmsOpen.restype = c_void_p
dll.cmsClose.argtypes = c_void_p,
dll.cmsClose.restype = c_int

handle = dll.cmsOpen(15, 3)
print(handle)
dll.cmsClose(handle)
```